# Why is it that the lack of an answer prevents the marking of a question as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

I don't understand why I can't mark a question as a duplicate. There is this question asked just now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844721/laravel-4-seo-friendly-pagination-url. There is an exact duplicate question asked four months earlier, [Laravel pagination pretty URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974404/laravel-pagination-pretty-url).

But I can't submit a close vote for "duplicate" - it says *"This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer"*.

Just because there is no (good) answer to a question does not stop it being a duplicate question.

If the OP of the duplicate question wants an answer - he can post a bounty on the target question to generate interest (which is why we have that function in the first place).

Comment: Simple solution, up vote the best answer in the target question?

Comment: No - because I dont know if any of those answers are actually correct - tbh I dont like any of them

Comment: Someone has just upvoted a question in that thread - which starts with "Here's a hacky workaround..." - so not exactly what I would upvote myself...

Comment: And that assumes there is an answer in the first place in the target question. I should still be able to mark a question as duplicate - to point everyone interested in that solution to one place.

Comment: Alternatively, the approach would be to flag it for a mod to force the dup as described in [Duplicate does not have upvoted answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202018/duplicate-does-not-have-upvoted-answers), and then there's [We should be able to close questions as duplicates of any question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165928/we-should-be-able-to-close-questions-as-duplicates-of-any-question)

Comment: Thanks. I tried searching MetaSO for duplicate question before I asked  - didnt see the other Meta section -  Oh the irony of a duplicate question about duplicate questions :)

Comment: @MichaelT re: Simple solution, up vote the best answer in the target question?" I can't do that if the newer question is a duplicate of another question where the only (or truly best) answer is mine and the previous asker couldn't be bothered to accept. I've encountered that situation a few times.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense, surely the system could reverse the vote and mark the old one as the duplicate :)  But then again, that duplicate is going to disappear quickly.  Such questions are not preserved.

Comment: See also: ["We should be able to close questions as duplicates of any question"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165928/we-should-be-able-to-close-questions-as-duplicates-of-any-question), which is from when this was first put into place.

Comment: Slightly less simple solution. Upvote an answer on the target question. VTC as dupe. Undo your vote. Though not sure if that would stop others from agreeing with the VTC.

Comment: @MichaelT That *would* work, except there are times when I'm the one who answered the question I would like to mark the current question a duplicate of.  I can't upvote myself (and sometimes, mine is the only answer to the question, so I can't temporarily upvote the other answers).

Comment: BTW, this is a general comment–in this specific case, it's pretty clear that the question is a duplicate–but can someone who says "I don't know if any of those answers are actually correct" make the determination of whether or not a question is a duplicate or not? I've seen some questions closed as duplicates that had subtle differences that were not covered in the supposed "original" question.

Comment: Yes I can @GSP. I am the 2nd top answerer for the Laravel4 tag. So I can easily identify a very specific duplicate question. I just have not run the specific code in the answers provided in the original question - and as I said "tbh I dont like any of them" - so it is not for me to mark them as correct or upvote them.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange as I said, it's more of a general comment not this specific case.

Comment: This is probably done so that you mark the question with no answers as a duplicate, and that way anyone searching for an answer to either question will be linked to some answers, regardless of which question they find first.

Comment: *Bump*. 2 years later this is still a problem. Can we please have this silly restriction removed?

Comment: Bump *again*. stackoverflow.com/q/45390867 and stackoverflow.com/q/45389978 quote the same code (with the same formatting), have nearly equivalent titles, and were asked within two hours of each other. The newer is a clear duplicate of the older, and yet we're not permitted to so much as flag the one for moderator attention.

Comment: @QED: Flagging _is_ the right response when you think there's rule evasion going on: [Duo of buddies can circumvent duplicate closures under the new rule requiring an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171371)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Very sensible idea.  You should be able to mark **a question as a duplicate** if ........ wait for it ...... the question is a duplicate.

It's irrelevant if an answer has been given, and/or if ticked/voted.

Great point.

--

NB -- Just as Shift says below: "no, it stops the same question being asked multiple times. If the question couldnt (wouldnt) be answered the first time, why have multiple copies?"

Comment: @JoeBlow (1) They don't like change, (2) they like things the way they are or (3) they just think your proposal isn't a good one - you can't really know which one it is - and changing just for the sake of changing is illogical - if you have something that well works (not saying [so] is working well though), why change it? Ignoring the emotional aspect that one may like change in itself, but bad changes kills sites - is that short time of feeling slightly good about the change worth it?

Comment: The whole idea was that telling the user the question is a duplicate is kind of useless if he can't find good answers at the old question.

Comment: @RaduMurzea - no, it stops the same question being asked multiple times. If the question couldnt (wouldnt) be answered the first time, why have multiple copies. The real problem is what happens when the "second" question gets answered, and meanwhile people searching come across the "first" question - they have no idea it is answered elsewhere....

Comment: Perhaps a better idea is when a duplicate question is linked, the original question (with no accepted answer) is "bumped" to the top of peoples lists - to give it new attention...? Or just stick to the bounty solution.

Comment: **no, it stops the same question being asked multiple times** yes, exactly -- of course that's true.

Comment: I don't dig up old questions. If something was asked 2 years ago and never got answered, then maybe no one (that could answer it) was around to see it. There is absolutely no reason why someone shouldn't re-ask the question, especially if the old question was years old.

Comment: In this case, the dupe question would likely get more upvotes and more answers, while the old question is still sitting around empty. Simply mark the old question as a dupe of the new one. This is no different from marking a new question as a dupe of the old so people know that the question was answered somewhere.

Comment: Pointing someone to an unanswered duplicate where the initial OP could easily be long gone is pointless. Unless that question is already as answerable as possible the new asker is going to have to attempt to hijack the question.

Comment: the overwhelming reality is THE CURRENT DUPLICATE SYSTEM IS TOTAL CRAP ANYWAY .. it's just a mess.  if you see something marked duplicate - so what? you just click around and read them all anyway.  it's not seneibls to think some incredibly fine distinction between duplicate display, or whatever, would matter.

Comment: @JoeBlow I don't see a problem with marking a chronologically older question as a duplicate of a chronologically newer question.

Comment: MxyL, sure - you're right.  pnuits -- **who cares**?  Duplicate is a very simple word in English with clear meaning.  If the **question** is a duplicate, mark it so.  (You guys are sort of talking about a special system for "marking answers duplicate" .. or something like that.)

Comment: @TomášZato Voting on meta generally means "I agree"/"I disagree", rather than "You make a good point"/"You suck"

Comment: If the old question hasn't been answered, it probably never will be, so you are blocking that user from getting an answer. If you let the new question stand, maybe someone will answer it. If anything, the old question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: "If the question couldnt (wouldnt) be answered the first time, why have multiple copies?" - FAIL. Questions are asked multiple times. See [Original Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197777/google-play-openssl-warning-message/24234391), [Re-asked 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24211025/openssl-security-alert-mail-from-google-play-for-anfroid-apps-created-with-flash), [Re-asked 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214034/openssl-security-alert-mail-from-google-play-for-android-apps).

Comment: Still the case. Run into it again today. On one hand we want a clean site, on the other hand we prevent ourselves from cleaning it up because of some bureaucratic BS. @BostonJohn: NOte that the answer alone is not sufficient. The answer must also be upvoted or accepted. IOW one is not even able to do it by answering one and dup-vote the other. Let alone the fact, that it takes more than one vote anyway, AFAIK. I can't see how that particular rule adds any value whatsoever.

Answer (score 32):

**Preamble:**

We're increasingly focused on how to reduce the question noise on SO, and we think Duplicates are probably the most important thing to find and kill. We'll be sharing a few ideas for feedback shortly - we're still trying to figure out which ones we think can be rolled out sooner rather than later.

**Amble:**

But this suggestion has challenges as a solution:  Letting people mark unanswered questions as dupe-targets may actually hurt signal, and will do very little about noise.

**THE SIGNAL PROBLEM: Until one of the questions has answers, it's very hard to know which one has the better chance of becoming the canonical reference.**

1. **We don't know which question is better yet.** If someone asks a question today that appears to describe the same situation as an old question, which one is more likely to be answered? We just don't know. In fact, the new one may have a better shot:

   - Assuming it's not word-for-word identical, you can guess that the new version has decent odds of being more clearly written than a version of the question that wasn't answered so far. (No information on answerability vs. negative info on the old one)
   - It has an author who actively cares now, and is more likely to respond to requests for more info if needed than an older, unanswered one.
2. **It's *sometimes* hard to be really sure if unanswered questions are evenreally dupes**.  Remember that duplicates should meet *both* of the following criteria:

   1. They are asking how to deal with the same problem.
   2. The same solution set applies to both.

   Until there are answers, two questions that appear to be duplicates may be answerable enough that they can't be closed as "unclear" but can be describing the same problem with two different underlying needs or causes, that don't come out until someone answers, and the OP says, "Yeah, but that's not helpful because [X]

It doesn't make a ton of sense to have someone's new question pointing to a less detailed one from months back, that might not even be addressing the same need.

**THE NOISE BENEFIT:**  All of the above would be moot if these were a big part of our duplicate problem, but the scenarios they impact are pretty limited:

**There just aren't that many places where two questions aren't closable for other reasons, but neither have useful-appearling answers yet.**  It totally comes up, as examples above show, but that noise is such a small part of the dupe problem we want to fix, that risking losing the potentially better one based on which came first just isn't worth it.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, the **question** may be duplicated, but that doesn't mean that two questions that ask the same thing are automatically eligible to be closed as a duplicate.

Check the flavor text for "Close as Duplicate":

> This question has been asked before and **already has an answer**. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.

How could a question truly be duplicated (as in, ask the same question and already have an answer) if there's no [upvoted or otherwise canonically accepted] answer on it?

Comment: "...but that doesn't mean two questions that ask the same thing are automatically eligible to be closed as a duplicate" - but why not? If they ask *exactly* the same thing, then by definition the answers should *eventually* be the same, and thus it is a duplicate?

Comment: Oh - and the flavor text is the whole point of this post. I know it says " no upvoted or otherwise canonically accepted" - I'm asking why a duplicate *question* needs an answer on another *question*. The question itself is the duplicate.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange two questions may look the same (think "I have a nullreferenceexception"), but have very different answers.  It's hard to tell what is what unless the target question has an answer.

Comment: @mydogisbox - well in my example that I listed above - that is simply not correct. If someone asks "what is 1+1?", and someone else asks "what is 1+1?" - I dont need to see any answers to know they are *the same question*.

Comment: I'm not saying this is always the case, I'm just saying the two cases are indistinguishable until they both have accepted answers.

Comment: @mydogisbox: I'd weaken that to them having an upvoted answer, since not everyone accepts answers.

Comment: Maybe the phrasing should be changed.  I've seen 2 questions pop up a day apart from each other that asked exactly the same thing.  Just because the first question doesn't have an answer doesn't make the second question not a duplicate.

Comment: **So our definition of "duplicate" is wrong.** I made this point when the policy first changed, and it's still important. The current policy says that as long as your question hasn't yet received an answer, *you can keep asking it over and over again*.

Comment: I guess the policymakers felt that a question is duplicate only when the intention is the same. Two people could ask very similar questions, but meant completely different things for various reasons: lack of info, different context, etc.

Comment: This invites site clutter and indirectly causes the site to appear less useful than it really can be.

Comment: I don't see the purpose of this answer - it just restates what the OP already knows. He's proposing a *change* of behaviour, which would presumably result in the close wording changing accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

> Just because there is no (good) answer to a question does not stop it
>   being a duplicate question.
>
> If the OP of the duplicate question wants an answer - he can post a
>   bounty on the target question to generate interest (which is why we
>   have that function in the first place).

This bothers me. If the answers on a certain question are soo crappy that you don't want to spend an upvote on it, you should not direct a new user to that question to find his/her answer. It doesn't stop it from being a duplicate, but it stops it from being **useful**. StackOverflow is a Q&A site, where people expect answers to their questions, not to be sent on a tour to answers **that do not answer their question**.

A new user should never be 'out of luck' because someone, somewhere asked a question that remotely resembles their question if that question does not answer their question. A new user cannot put a bounty on a question.

By upvoting, or accepting, an existing answer, you show that there is some worth in the answer on the old question. If there is no such worth, do not expect that it will help OP either.

Comment: But then what happens if/when someone answers both questions with the same answer? Duplicate questions and answers. And meanwhile - what about the original quesiton asker - shouldnt they be told of the "new" question, which may get an answer?

Comment: "it stops it from being useful" - I like the distinction. You can always close the question with the crappy answer as duplicate of the new, hopefully better answered, question!

Comment: If the user had done their research, they would have included things they tried (bonus points for referencing questions they looked at that didn't help) as part of their question and shown why they didn't work.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  If I'm searching regarding Question X, I certainly, absolutely, want to know any/all duplicates of that question on the site.  That's even more true if the question is tricky/unanswered.  Information wants to be free.

Comment: *If the answers on a certain question are soo crappy that you don't want to spend an upvote on it* It's also possible that the user raising the flag knows enough of the language to recognize a duplicate, but not enough to recognize a good answer. Take [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895580/how-to-get-url-after-equal-sign-in-javascript) as an example. I understand what OP is asking for, and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) is a duplicate with lots of answers. But I can't tell if one of those answers is good.

Comment: @JoeBlow You can still make questions linked. If both are uneligible to be marked as duplicate, then likely there aren't many Linked questions, so this linking will not get lost in the mass of linked posts either. Also, you can say in comment the word "duplicate", even if you can't close by that reason.

Comment: "A new user cannot put a bounty on a question." There are a great many privileges new users lack, most of which they have the opportunity to earn simply by contributing to the site. Why on earth should they be entitled to duplicate existing questions when we already have clear mechanisms both for "bumping" the existing question and for earning that privilege in the first place?

Answer (score -6):

The basic problem is, without any references, there is no way to know if it is a duplicate. Take this example:

> What is 1+1?

Depending on the frame of reference, the answer can be:

- 2
- 11
- some approximation approaching 2, depending on the language implementation of floating point arithmetic (i.e., double or half precision floating point format, some older compiler not compliant with the IEEE 754 Standard, etc.).

This doesn't even have to depend on tags. Both 2 and 11 would be viable answers for a javascript tag, for example. And whole papers have been written about the 3rd answer.

We try to limit and define the references with tags, requests for more information, etc., but in the end, can not always sure what the proper answer to the question should be. This specific question can easily be and perhaps should be marked as a duplicate, unless it can be qualified as something like:

> What is 1+1 in floating point arithmetic with a FORTRAN 74 compiler on
>   VMS VAX?

In a perfect forum, all three answers would be on the same question, and it would be, like many of the questions already answered on this site, THE canonical reference and number one on google.

But in absence of that, I think unless you are sure, which in the original poster's question he is, with good reason, the best answer would be to link the questions, instead of marking as a duplicate.