# Get notification when a question you answered gets a bounty

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, bounty, notifications

The linked post actually does not contain an answer, and by definition does not answer my question. This is a meta channel where communicating this issues of the main site are most important. I don't see a bounty mechanism, and I don't see any other way to refresh the linked question. So what we have here are 2 questions that will not be discussed further.

---

Over a month ago, I had answered a question that I had just ran into. My answer solved my issue, so i posted it.

Now, I came back on here and found 2 notifications from 2 people that upvoted my answer. I checked and was surprised to learn that a bounty was set for the question.

It was set by another user, and I just found out 6 hours before the bounty will end. I put in the extra effort to answer the question the first time, I would have liked to have had extra time to figure out an extended solution and have a back-and-forth conversation with the bounty-setter to get the correct solution.

Now, I have to put out a general statement to the user and wait for their reply

**It just seems reasonable that I - as a previous answerer - would have received a notification when the bounty was set....not when users decided to upvote my previous answer because the bounty deadline is almost over.**

So, just to be clear, this is a feature request for all previous answerers (and possibly the OP) to get a notification when a bounty is set.

Very similar question that went nowhere with upvotes - [Notify authors when a bounty is offered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299028/2333021)

Comment: Sorry, but I should not have gotten a close vote....the duplicate question close vote states ...`This question has been asked before **and** already has an answer.` As you can clearly see...there are no answers to that question

Comment: Meh... @Chris.  I still think it can be. Seems to be a controversial issue. But I go with accepted answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256054/this-question-does-not-have-an-upvoted-or-accepted-answer/256056#256056 there.

Comment: OK, but this is Meta, and having a conversation seem more important than marking it "duplicate" with both having no answer

Comment: So how can I get that question "refreshed" so people can start talking about it. I see no need to actually edit the post...but that is the only way I can think of refreshing it

Comment: @CRABOLO I can fully understand for the main site....which that question was asking about. But this is Meta, and we are talking about the main site...so closing this question because it is a "duplicate" will mean  we have 2 questions that will not be discussed. Sounds counter intuitive. But your logic is sound for the main site.

Comment: and now we have 2 questions that should be discussed and voted upon? How will SO evaluate whether to implement the feature? What if two discussions evolve separately and propose 2 different solutions? Do we then need a third question to find out which of the two to choose? ;-) Would it not be better to just have one "thread" for discussion? I think one of the two questions should be closed.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit I commented on that question 5 days ago, and the OP has not been back on there. That question as of right now is abandoned. If you can revive it, then do it. I cannot figure out how to. But I can revive this question if it is reopened.

Comment: We have 22 upvotes here on my question and 13 upvotes on the Duplicate question. Neither have an answer. I am active, but my question is closed. The other question is open but is not active with no  activity for 1.5 months. Like I said....if you can revive the other question...then do it. I want to discuss this

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski ok i think this is misleading to a lot of people. What is meant by being active? The question does not need to be updated to active. A question which is not closed can be answered, commented, upvoted. I would say it being active is a question of that being done. So it is totally possible for you to write an answer to the other question which then can be commented and upvoted/downvoted again. Also what i think in general the "feature request" process is a bit intransparent. Who's responsible for handling them? How do we get their feedback? What should our expectations be?

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski so i totally get it if you're frustrated (i'm a bit as well). I expect you had good intentions and you may feel you were basically punished for them. But closing this Q is not about people wanting to publish you but i guess it's rather a symptom of the system not working very well. It get's people frustrated without providing an alternative how the positive energy can be invested rewardingly. Expectations are left unmanaged (or rather, it actually seems that there are possibilities which then basically vanish into thin air).

Comment: @batteryBackupUnit....yes, I know people can still comment on the other question, but nobody actually is.....and the longer it is not, the less people will see it because it is buried so far.....hence being inactive by default,  not technically. I would love to post an *answer* but I can't because I don't have an answer.....I have a concern about the current system; hence my question to communicate