# Why can't I close a question as duplicate when I paste an SO link?

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

I tried to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36598439/c-sharp-create-a-route-from-pair-objects) by pasting [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36598168/need-to-sort-complex-objects-like-dominoe) a commenter provided. The **Vote to Close** button remained disabled:

[image]

The placeholder text in the text box states that a link to a question is acceptable:

[image]

yet this did not enable the button. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

**Edit**

Obviously (now), I did miss something (see my comments below as to why). The explanation below the text box does not really state **why** I can't mark it as a duplicate; it states **what** the condition is that is blocking it from being marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Don't you see that red text there?! **"This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer"**

Comment: The question you want to use as a dupe does not have an upvoted or accepted answer. This very message is displayed in red below the text box.

Comment: It is written there in red.. "This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer"

Comment: Ok, fair enough. UE I suppose, but why does that matter. The question *is* a duplicate.

Comment: @Kit, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256054/464709.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, thanks for the link. All of that reasoning seems a bit esoteric to me.

Comment: @Rizier123 -- again, UE. Good design should prevent UE. I "see" the message now. FTR, I temporarily have the use of one eye, and so the subtlety of the red and nearby black text is lost on me even though I am *not* color blind. The message also does not say *why* that's an issue; I'm guessing because they can't explain it succinctly. It's funny how you have to explain things because of your visceral reaction to negative votes.

Comment: As per your edit: the rationale is that the duplicate should ideally provide an *answer* (at least upvoted or accepted) as that shows some sign of being useful as a target. Just closing questions as dupes of questions without answers could lead to a frustrating experience of keep hopping from post to post finding that someone else had the same problem as you did but still not finding an answer ([relevant xkcd](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wisdom_of_the_ancients.png)).

Comment: The error doesn't _need_ to explain the _"why"_ of a rule, just what the rule is. The rule is a question must have an upvoted or accepted answer for you to close questions as duplicates of it. If you want the _why,_ you come to the help center/Meta and search, or ask if searching returns nothing.

Comment: @Kendra I'm not sure I agree with you. Jon gave a succinct reason above. If you wordsmithed that a tad, and put it inline I wouldn't have to go anywhere. I personally ask why immediately if I don't understand the rule.

Comment: Errors are there to tell you _"Hey, this didn't work, this is the rule/issue."_ They are _not_ there to tell you _"Hey, this didn't work, this is the rule/issue, and this is the rationale for the rule/issue."_ I would _never_ want to put the rationale for why something threw an error _in_ an error message- I'd just want to tell the user what happened, and how they can fix it if they can. For instance, if we have some weird validation rule (we do on our current project), I don't want to explain even a short reason for a rule- Let the user ask the person/people who made the rule why it's a rule.

Comment: @Kendra I agree with *what*, making it actionable for the user, and even with your "no why", but only *if* you can't explain it well or succinctly. If you can, you could save some time and frustration. That's the first thing I expect in [good UX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742471(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I see nothing in there that says to explain why a rule was made. Explain why the error occurred, yes. That was done in this case, as the error occurred _because the question you picked did not have an upvoted or accepted answer._ There is no reason to explain why the rule exists as that doesn't matter to the user as much as _fixing the error that occurred._ Quoting your own link: _"good error messages have: A problem. States that a problem occurred. A cause. Explains why the problem occurred. A solution. Provides a solution so that users can fix the problem."_ Not listed: Why a rule exists.

Comment: Ah, I get your point. Yes, the user doesn't need a history lesson, but it could be a bit better worded: "A question without an upvoted or accepted answer is not yet a good candidate to be marked as a duplicate" or some such. When I read that original text I thought it was just giving more information about the question in general because it appeared immediately as part of the dialog.

Comment: Also, why not just hide or disable the **duplicate of...** button in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The explanation below the text box does not really state **why** I can't mark it as a duplicate; it states **what** the condition is that is blocking it from being marked as a duplicate.

That would be because "why" should be obvious.

If a question has no answers, or no upvoted/accepted answers, then the question is effectively unanswered. Marking a question as a duplicate of an unanswered question helps nobody. People looking for answers will not find any, either on the duplicate or the original.

Marking a question as a duplicate closes a question. This means that someone who might want to answer it now cannot do so. You might say that they could just answer the question it is a duplicate of, but now you're forcing them to read two questions before they can answer it.

Two unanswered questions are more likely to draw answers than one. And it doesn't matter if the new or old one gets an answer; so long as one of them gets one, we have an answer. The other question can then be marked as a duplicate, thus fulfilling that purpose.

Comment: I get, now, the rationale that marking an unanswered/un-upvoted question lowers the potential utility of SO, but what I was *thinking* was "I saw two questions that are duplicates of each other" and "I'm on this one so I will mark it as a duplicate." Not, "oh maybe I should mark the *other one* as the duplicate. It's subtle, but I understand.