# How to handle a duplicate of unanswered question

Tags: discussion, flags, unanswered-questions

Consider following scenario:

Some time ago, I've posted an answer to a question. It never got accepted, question didn't get any other answers and therefore question itself remained open.

Later on I've found another question with a little bit different scenario, but I could see, that the core of the problem was the same. I'm mentioning the different scenario, because this is (I think) the reason, why the poster of a newer question couldn't find the old one.

I wanted to flag this newer question as a duplicate, but documentation says I shouldn't, because the original question still doesn't have an answer. So I decided to go to that old question, copy my answer and paste it in this new question. I assumed that since this is a fresh question, my answer could get accepted fast and then I can go to that old one and flag that one as a duplicate. My new answer got deleted and a moderator (kindly) asked me to not duplicate my answers.

Here is the comment:

> Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, tailor your answers to the question.

I couldn't ask this moderator, what should I do, when the duplicate is unanswered, so I've searched StackExchange Meta. I've found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled/10844#10844) well rated answer, which says, that I should flag a question for a moderator attention and explain my reasoning. So I did that.

Nothing happened, so I've let it go for the moment. I thought that either I've used the flag a wrong way or moderators are too busy or they don't have enough information to decide that these questions are indeed duplicates.

I waited some time and this new question was still unanswered. Finally I felt bad for the author, so I've decided to comment a hint and pointed out that his question is probably a duplicate. I've also attached a link to that older question.

Author upvoted my answer on the older question, told me that It worked for him and thanked me. Not long afterwards some other moderator closed his question as a duplicate.

I'm wondering if this other moderator closed it because of my original flag or because the author of a question unofficially accepted my answer by upvoting my answer on the old question.

My main question though is: How should've I correctly approached this? Where did I make mistakes? What could've I made better?

Comment: You should have flagged the question as a duplicate, instead of repeating your answer.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ : Like I stated in my question, documentation says I shouldn't. Also [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320931/why-cant-i-close-a-question-as-duplicate-when-i-paste-an-so-link/320947#320947) question suggests it's even impossible.

Comment: You are probably mistaking _"because the original question still doesn't have an answer"_ for _"because the original question still doesn't have an **accepted** answer"_. It's not necessary that the answer you gave was accepted by the OP, to use that question as a duplicate. The crucial point is that there's an answer at all.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: You are indeed right, I assumed at that time, that _answer = accepted answer_ . It is though still necessary to have at least an _upvoted answer_. What would you suggest, if my answer doesn't have any votes? Let's assume less busy field/tag, where (up/down)votes are much less frequent.

Comment: The other key phrase in the moderator's comment is "don't post **identical** answers". You copied and pasted the exact same words/code. Don't do that, even if the other question has no answers (accepted or otherwise). Make sure your answer includes aspects of the question such that it uniquely answers that question.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan When I saw, that my message got deleted, I learned, that copy/paste is an undesired way of answering on SO. I understand reasoning behind it. Even though I think that in this particular case it could do more good than bad, I won't do it anymore. I also think though, that adding to my answer just for the sake of making it different is also not a good way of doing things. These two questions were in their core duplicates, therefore I would still be in core making duplicate answers. I would just add extra unnecessary sauce around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Prominently link to the previous question in a comment**, e.g. along the lines of: *"(closely) related: <url>"*, or: *"The same core problem in <different environment>: <url>"* . The core values of SO cannot help any further here:

- It is *not* appropriate to close as a duplicate. As long as there are no answers, being forcibly redirected will not help either the new asker or further readers -- because there's ultimately no answer still.
- So, to direct the readers to the other question *non-forcibly* is all you can possibly do -- in the hopes that the non-intersecting pieces of information the other one has will possibly help them tackle the problem.

---

MathOverflow community has invented a workflow for a similar situation: [dealing with open problems](https://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic):

- When a problem turns out to be equivalent to a known open problem, the *question* is converted to community wiki and is transformed to ask: "What is known about this problem? What are some possible ways to approach this problem? What are some ways that people have tried to attack it before, and with what results?", essentially becoming a repository of knowledge about the "work in progress".

This approach won't work as is for SO, however, and will need corrections if considering it:

- Technical problems with the same core reason can manifest themselves in fundamentally different ways.
- And SO *needs* separate questions for majorly different manifestations so that the fellow who has the problem can google a solution by his manifestation's keywords.
- Strictly speaking, this applies to maths just the same. The fundamental difference is:
- SO gives practical advice rather than high theory foundations. If the core reason is the same but different actions are needed due to the environment differences, the answer will be different -- though it can link to others for background exposition.