# How do I flag a duplicate question that has not been answered?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions

Yesterday I flagged a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49962745/how-do-i-make-this-simple-code-work) because it was an exact copy of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49962017/does-anyone-know-how-to-make-this-simple-code-work).
Because (unlike the proposed duplicate [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326263/how-to-handle-a-duplicate-of-unanswered-question)) *the original post had not been answered at all*, I was not able to flag the second post as a duplicate, which is what I would have liked to do. So instead I flagged it for moderator attention with the message

> This is an exact copy of a previously asked question

and a link to the original post.

This flag was declined with the message

> Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see What is Flagging?

So how should I have flagged the post? I couldn't use the "duplicate" flag because of the requirement that the original post had an answer, and none of the other options: "spam", "rude or abusive", "should be closed" or "very low quality" seemed to fit.

Comment: “...but can’t close as posted under different accounts and no answer” would likely be accepted instead. More details why you can’t perform moderation action the better.

Comment: @FeiXiang as I explained in my question, I did give a link to the original post when I flagged the copy.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that's fair but it was actually posted by the same user.

Comment: @StephenRauch I have edited my post to explain why this is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: On meta, the lack of an answer on a previous question, does not make it not a duplicate.

Comment: @Nick posts you've linked to posted by different users. Are you sure you posted correct links? (note that you can always dup posts by the same user irrespective of presence of answers)

Comment: @StephenRauch, What I was saying was that the post on SO had no answers (neither of them did). The question on meta that you proposed as a duplicate was about a post on SO that did have an answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov you're right the names are different (they're so similar I hadn't noticed). Interesting that both have been users for the same amount of time.

Comment: @Nick Oops, missed that part about the link, sorry. I guess the mod just didn't look into the link and mistook it as a misuse of a mod flag.