# Closed question as duplicate of unanswered question by same user

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I just came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526164/convert-unity-c-sharp-code-to-mobile-touch-control) and voted to close it as it is an exact duplicate of a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495875/converting-mouse-inputs-to-touch-inputs-for-pong-like-game) the **same user** had asked a day earlier. (This was the fourth close vote)

However, the original question from the day before doesn't have any answers (and therefore no accepted or upvoted answer either). *Let's forget about the fact that the question isn't good as it is - hence all the downvotes - and needs clarification and a sign of an attempt being made and so on...*

This made me wonder a bit because I'm pretty sure that SO doesn't let you close questions as duplicates of other questions that [don't have an upvoted or accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256054/this-question-does-not-have-an-upvoted-or-accepted-answer). In fact, I even saw this *error* message sometime in the course of last week when trying to close another question.

Now, how is it possible that this question did get closed as a duplicate? Does the system make an exception if it's a question by the same user? And if this is the case, why doesn't the duplicate question just get auto-deleted instead of just closed? - especially in this case where the *duplicate* is really just the same user asking the exact question two days in a row because the first attempt was downvoted and not answered.

Comment: Questions from the same author can be closed as duplicates, [answered or not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165933/190066). This exception also applies to meta posts.

Comment: That's true, but it's strange that this is [not mentioned in the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is an exception to the "must have an answer" rule for dupe candidates if the target was asked by the same user.